# How to go back to previous search results

Tags: reactjs

I have a `List.js` page and a `Detail.js` page. I use `<Link to={{ pathname: '/detail/'+ID}}>View More</Link>` to navigate from list to detail page.

Now, how do I go back to the list page with all the search `results(list)`?

The list component renders list of items `{items}` passed down from `App.js`. Should I access the search query from `App.js` or `{items}` in the `List.js` and how to do it? I am learning react-router now. Thanks.

**index.js**

```
 <BrowserRouter>
   <Switch>
      <Route path='/' component={App} />
      <Route path='/detail/:ID' component={Detail} />
   </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

**App.js**

```
class App extends Component  {
   state = { query:null, items:[] }

   componentDidMount() {
     const {query} = this.state;
     this.runSearch({query});
   }

   runSearch = async(query) => { const response= await axios.get('apiurl\', { params:{ query: query} });
       this.setState({items: response.data});
   }

   render() { 
     return <div>
         {/*search bar*/}
     <List items={this.state.items} />
     </div>
   }
}
```

**List.js**

```
const List=({items})=>{
      //map list
      const renderedList= items.map(item=>{
          return (<div>
          <div class="content">
            <Link  to={{ pathname: 'detail/'+item.ID}}                    
              key={item.ID}>
              View More
            </Link>    
          </div></div>)
      });

      return (
        <Router><div>
          {renderedList}
          <Route path="detail/:ID" component={Detail} />
          </div></Router>);
}
export default List;
```

**Detail.js**

```
class Detail extends Component {
    state={
       ID: this.props.match.params.ID,
       result:[]};
       componentDidMount(){
          this.runSearch();
       }

       runSearch=async()=>{
          const response= await axios.get('API\?{this.props.match.params.ID}')
                 this.setState({result: response.data});
       }

       render(){
          return (
            <div>
            Detail: ID {this.props.match.params.ID}
                Name {this.state.result["name"]}
            </div>
          ); 
       }   
};

export default withRouter(Detail);
```

Comment: Please provide some code so that everyone here understands your query better.

Comment: I added code above. Thanks.

Comment: Well there are multiple approaches. In general what I do is instead of creating a new page and **route** for `Details` component I will just render a `Details` component when user clicks on the list item.

Comment: I want to have a new route for Detail so user can bookmark the URL, something like /detail/ID. I can create a  popup window to load the Detail component but I don't know how to change the URL with ID so user can save the URL.

Comment: Then what you can do is you could resubmit the same search on `componentDidMount` of your `List` component. Assuming you can recover the search filter(s).

Comment: My search filter is in App.js. List.js holds search results passed down from App.js. How to pass the search results from List to Detail and then from Detail back to List when click go back to list?